# Python Multiprocessing Early Termination

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

While my script is running, it is possible that an error may occur at some point. In that case, all processes should be properly terminated, an error message should be returned, and the script should exit.

The code I have now seems to not fulfill those requirements yet. When an error occurs, it is sent to `report_error()`, the script ends up hanging in Terminal, and Activity Monitor shows many Python processes still running.

**Environment**

- Mac OS X 10.8.5
- Python 3.3.3

What is the correct way to terminate all processes from any point in the script?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import sys
from multiprocessing import Pool


# Global variables.

input_files = [
    'test_data_0.csv',
    'test_data_1.csv'
]


def report_error(error):

    # Reports errors then exits script.
    print("Error: {0}".format(error), file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

    # What I really want is to report the error, properly terminate all processes,
    # and then exit the script.


def read_file(file):

    try:
        # Read file into list.
    except Exception as error:
        report_error(error)


def check_file(file):

    # Do some error checking on file.
    if error:
        report_error(error)


def job(file):

    # Executed on each item in input_files.

    check_file(file)
    read_file(file)


def main():

    # Sets up a process pool. Defaults to number of cores.
    # Each input gets passed to job and processed in a separate process.
    p = Pool()
    p.map(job, input_files)

    # Closing and joining a pool is important to ensure all resources are freed properly.
    p.close()
    p.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want an error in one of the workers to cause all other workers, and the parent process, to terminate?

Comment: Also, do you care about what value is returned from `job`? If so, do you care what *order* the results come back in?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, using `sys.exit()` to kill the child worker process will actually break the pool, and make the `map` command hang forever. Currently `multiprocessing` doesn't recover properly from crashes in the worker processes while the worker is processing a job (there is a bug report with a patch that addresses this issue [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue9205), for what its worth).

There are a couple of ways you can do what you *actually* want to do. Since it seems like you don't care about the values being returned from the worker functions, the easiest is to use [`imap_unordered`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap_unordered) instead of `map`, raise an exception from the worker when there's a failure, and then simply iterate over the iterator returned by `imap_unordered`:

```
def report_error(error):

    # Reports errors then exits script.
    print("Error: {0}".format(error), file=sys.stderr)
    raise error # Raise the exception

...

def main():
    p = Pool()
    try:
        list(p.imap_unordered(job, input_files))
    except Exception:
        print("a worker failed, aborting...")
        p.close()
        p.terminate()
    else:
        p.close()
        p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

With `imap_unordered`, results will be returned to the parent as soon as the child sends them. So, if a child sends an exception back to the parent, it will immediately get re-raised in the parent process. We catch that exception, print a message, and then terminate the pool.

Comment: Late question here. The solution works, but I don' understand. Why is it necessary for the child to explicitly raise an exception? If the child fails, wouldn't it raise an exception naturally?

Comment: @Student if the child function "fails" by throwing an exception, then no additional raise is needed. The OPs child method seemed to do some kind of reporting on errors, implying it was catching them. In that case, the explict raise was needed so an exception made it back to the parent.

Comment: If I have a KeyboardInterupt while the pool is running, does it cause the child to raise a KeyboardInterupt? If it does then by right I won't need to get the child to explicitly raise an exception. What I am seeing is that when I KeyboardInterupt the pool, the program just hangs. But if I use except to catch KeyboardInterupt in the child, then raise within the except, then in the parent use `except Exception` to close() and terminate like what you did, then if I press control-C when the pool is running the program stops running as I would have wanted it to.

Comment: a) thank you for having an answer to this!
b) there is a seriously disturbing amount of prototyping and digging I had to do to make this work for what I consider to be the most popular use case

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why the `else` is needed. By that point all the processes have terminated and the `pool` is local. What are you closing and joining to?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer The processes in the pool don't terminate until after you call `close()`, and any outstanding work items running in them complete (or, if you call `terminate()` instead, the proceses exit without waiting for outstanding work to complete). Of course, they'll also terminate when the main process exits, so in this example it's not actually required, because there won't be any outstanding work we want to wait for. I just included it because in general it's a best practice to cleanly shut them down when you're done with them.